# How to join multiple tables with aliases

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join, codeigniter-3

I have 3 tables in database:

**teams**

> - id
> - name

**matches**

> - id (int)
> - team_home_id
> - team_away_id

**goals**

> - id
> - match_id
> - team_id
> - time

I need display names of teams in view where I get goals in controller.

I know that I should do join tables.

I have this code:

```
    public function get_goals() {
        $this->db->select('goals.*');
        $this->db->from('goals');
        $this->db->join('matches', 'matches.id = goals.match_id');
        $q = $this->db->get();

        return $q->result();
    }
```

and I don't know what next.

I need in view display names by:

**$goals->team_home_name** and **$goals->team_away_name**

Comment: use another query instead of join.

Comment: Add join on table 'teams ' in given SQL query, select field as per requirement and then pass that in view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get `$goals->team_home_name` and `$goals->team_away_name` result, use aliases like this :

```
public function get_goals() {
    $this->db->select('goals.*, home_team.name team_home_name, away_team.name team_away_name');
    $this->db->from('goals');
    $this->db->join('matches', 'matches.id = goals.match_id');
    $this->db->join('teams home_team', 'home_team.id = matches.team_home_id');
    $this->db->join('teams away_team', 'away_team.id = matches.team_away_id');
    $q = $this->db->get();

    return $q->result();
}
```

Comment: Ok, but $goals->team_home_name and $goals->team_away_name should be connected with matches.team_home_id and matches.team_away_id not goals.team_id. I do not know if it is understandable :(

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this:-

```
public function get_goals() {
    $this->db->select('g.* , t.name as team_home_name , t.name as team_away_name);
    $this->db->from('goals as g');
    $this->db->join('matches as m', 'm.id = g.match_id');
    $this->db->join('teams as t', 't.id = g.team_id');
    $q = $this->db->get();
    return $q->result();
}
```

Comment: Unknown column 't.team_home_name' in 'field list'

Comment: $this->db->select('g.* , t.name as team_home_name , t.name as team_away_name);

Answer (score 0):

U can use an alias by

guss the team_away_name and team_home_name from teams table

```
public function get_goals() {
        $this->db->select('goals.*, team.team_home_name, team.team_away_name');
        $this->db->from('goals');
        $this->db->join('matches', 'matches.id = goals.match_id');
        $this->db->join('teams as team', 'team.id = goals.team_id');
        $q = $this->db->get();

        return $q->result();
    }
```